# How to block on write nicely in linux character driver?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a linux character driver which implements a "tagged MUX" functionality writing to a special hardware link.

`write()` requests to the driver feed data into a `kfifo` and a separate kernel thread pulls the data from the FIFO as appropriate.  If the FIFO is full, user-space writers to the file descriptor should block until FIFO space is available.

How do you implement such blocking in a character device driver?

I tried this in the "write" handler of my character driver. The user-space process did indeed block when the FIFO was full but it could not be interrupted or killed.  Had to reboot the machine.

```
ssize_t
fifoWrite(struct file *pFile, const char __user *pUserData, size_t nBytes, loff_t *pOffset)
{
    unsigned char         *pktData = 0;

    pktData = memdup_user(pUserData, nBytes); // copy n bytes from user to kernel
    if (IS_ERR(pktData))
        return PTR_ERR(pktData);

    TDataPacket pkt;
    memcpy(pkt.buf, pktData, nBytes);

    while (kfifo_put(&pktFifo, pkt) == 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR MODULE_NAME": write - FIFO full\n");
        msleep(1000);
    }

    int fifoLen = kfifo_len(&clientInfo->pktFifo);

    printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": WRITE - %zu bytes. LEN %d\n", , nBytes, fifoLen);

    kfree(pktData);

    return nBytes;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to honor `O_NONBLOCK` open flag. Second, `read()` system call may return different error codes, the user space must respect that and act accordingly.

Comment: The driver does not implement `read` as it is not applicable to the underlying hardware. Sure, from the driver I can return `EAGAIN` if `O_NONBLOCK` is set.  How do I make `write` calls  interruptible when they block?  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/ERESTARTSYS (E.g., drivers/thunderbolt/debugfs.c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a long time, these resources proved to be very helpful:

- [Character Device Driver – Blocking IO using wait queues](https://www.emblogic.com/blog/12/character-device-driver-blocking-io-using-wait-queues/)
- [O'Reilly - Blocking I/O](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch05s02.html)
- [Linux Device Drivers, Dr. Wolfgang Koch](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/%7Eceepush81/slides/LinuDriv5.pdf)